# How to link multiple data tables to SQLite tables in a database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, dataadapter

In C# using SQLite, I have two datatables in my application. DT1 and DT2. Using DataAdaptor "DA" and Dataset "DS" I have to linked DT1 to a SQLIte table "Analyzer"- . I wanna be able to tie DT2 to another table in the same database as "Analyzer". How do I do this?

Do I use the same data adaptor or 2 different adaptors? Is there even a way to link tables under a common database in Sqlite? Do we use the same connection object? I'd appreciate it if someone could shed some light on to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: connecton object should be the same; try using 2 DataAdapters; for querying 2 similar tables at once (without the possibility of updates) use UNION (see: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use DataAdapters - one per table, and one DataSet per table. Share the connection, though. As @ralf.w. - you can use UNION and only have one of everything if you're not saving back to the DB.